# Online PHP syntax checker / validator

Tags: php, validation, syntax-checking

Could someone refer me to an online PHP validator? 
It would be of much help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of *validation* do you want ?

Comment: I would like one that would find the errors in my PHP script, display at which line the error is at, and possibly explain the error.

Comment: Perhaps you could write your own? Just need to use `php -l [filename]` to parse the php file, and not execute it.

Comment: Why an online validator instead of using an IDE such as NetBeans or ZendStudio? I think a really inquisitive web developer would use a desktop validator instead of an online validator, I would not trust the later to be more reliable...

Comment: @Jacob Could you explain in more detail what you just said?

Comment: @Jacob is `php -l [filename]` a parsing as part of php's compiler?

Comment: Try http://phpsyntaxchecker.com

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

You can validate on the command line using `php -l [filename]`, which does a syntax check only (lint). This will depend on your php.ini error settings, so you can edit you php.ini or set the error_reporting in the script.

Here's an example of the output when run on a file containing:

```
<?php
echo no quotes or semicolon
```

Results in:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in badfile.php on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in badfile.php on line 2

Errors parsing badfile.php
```

I suggested you build your own validator.

A simple page that allows you to upload a php file. It takes the uploaded file runs it through `php -l` and echos the output.

**Note**: this is not a security risk it does not execute the file, just checks for syntax errors.

Here's a really basic example of creating your own:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    passthru('php -l '.$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It being a security risk or not depends on where the file was uploaded.

Comment: If you don't have php in your `$PATH` variable you can `cd` to the directory where `php.exe` exists and call `php.exe -l C:\path\to\file.php`.

Answer (score 7):

I found this for online php validation:-

**http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one more for you that not only performs the `php -l` check for you, but also does some secondary analysis for mistakes that would not be considered invalid (e.g. declaring a variable with a double equal sign).

http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: When the file is too large, it throws Error 414 URI Too long

Answer (score 4):

Here is a similar question to yours. (Practically the same.)

[What ways are there to validate PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300544/what-ways-are-there-to-validate-php-code)

**Edit**

The top answer there suggest this resource:

http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v4/syntax-check.php

Comment: first link is dead `What ways are there to validate PHP code?`

Answer (score 1):

Ther's a new php code check online:

http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/

Answer (score 1):

http://phpcodechecker.com/ performs syntax check and a custom check for common errors.

I'm a novice, but it helped me.

Comment: Already covered by [Mario Lurig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010780/3303195).

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a good and simple site to check your php codes and share your code with fiends :

http://trycodeonline.com

Comment: does not exist anymore

Comment: Try http://phpsyntaxchecker.com

Comment: Try [php online](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox) This tool allow you to check your php codes, execute, and share your code with fiends.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested, an offline checker that does complicated type analysis:
http://strongphp.org
It is *not* online however.